# Is there a built-in Swift function to pad Strings at the beginning?

Tags: swift, string

The `String` function `padding(toLength:withPad:startingAt:)` will pad strings by adding padding characters on the end to "fill out" the string to the desired length.

Is there an equivalent function that will pad strings by prepending padding characters at the beginning?

This would be useful if you want to right-justify a substring in a monospaced output string, for example.

I could certainly write one, but I would expect there to be a built-in function, seeing as how there is already a function that pads at the end.

Comment: `let padded = String(repeating: " ", count: toLength - str.characters.count) + str`

Comment: Like I said, I could certainly write such a function. It's surprising the built-in function doesn't work from either end, or that there's not another padAtBeginning function.

Comment: The function you mention is not a built-in Swift function.  That comes from Foundation.

Comment: The function `func padding(toLength:withPad:startingAt:)` is listed in the Swift spec at [**swiftdoc.org**](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/String/#func-padding-tolength_withpad_startingat_), which made me think it was a language feature. I see now that it's flagged as Foundation. Has the SwiftDoc.org site always listed functions from the Foundation classes?

Comment: If you don't `import Foundation` (or `UIKit` or `Cocoa`) you'll get the error **error: value of type 'String' has no member 'padding'**

Comment: Good question about SwiftDoc.org.  It is confusing when apparent Swift features are not actually features of the language.

Comment: how about reversing the string, using the "built-in" `padding(toLength...)` and then reversing again?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by reversing the string, padding at the end, end then reversing again…

```
let string = "abc"

// Pad at end
string.padding(toLength: 7, withPad: "X", startingAt: 0)
// "abcXXXX"    

// Pad at start
String(String(string.reversed()).padding(toLength: 7, withPad: "X", startingAt: 0).reversed())
// "XXXXabc"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Swift string manipulations are a rehash of the old NSString class, I suppose Apple never bothered to complete the feature set and just gave us toll free bridging as mana from the gods.

Or, since Objective-C never shied away from super verbose yet cryptic code, they expect us to use the native function twice :

```
let a = "42"
"".padding(toLength:10, withPad:a.padding(toLength:10, withPad:"0", startingAt:0), startingAt:a.characters.count)

// 0000000042
```

.

[EDIT] Objective-C ranting aside, the solution is a bit more subtle than that and adding some more useful padding methods to the String type is probably going to make things easier to use and maintain:

For example:

```
extension String
{
   func padding(leftTo paddedLength:Int, withPad pad:String=" ", startingAt padStart:Int=0) -> String
   {
      let rightPadded = self.padding(toLength:max(count,paddedLength), withPad:pad, startingAt:padStart)
      return "".padding(toLength:paddedLength, withPad:rightPadded, startingAt:count % paddedLength) 
   }

   func padding(rightTo paddedLength:Int, withPad pad:String=" ", startingAt padStart:Int=0) -> String
   {
      return self.padding(toLength:paddedLength, withPad:pad, startingAt:padStart)
   }

   func padding(sidesTo paddedLength:Int, withPad pad:String=" ", startingAt padStart:Int=0) -> String
   {
      let rightPadded = self.padding(toLength:max(count,paddedLength), withPad:pad, startingAt:padStart)
      return "".padding(toLength:paddedLength, withPad:rightPadded, startingAt:(paddedLength+count)/2 % paddedLength)
   }
}
```

Comment: Here is a version that doesn't truncate longer strings: https://gist.github.com/tkafka/705437a358188e55076a0e4799131231